# Flowplayer controlbar D7

Tags: files

I've been trying to hide the controlbar when the canvas is being shown (the video has't been started up) and show a controlbar once the video has been started up. (see below) Thanks in advance :)

- here is how its now by default
  [image]
- here how I want it to looks like...
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

As the [Flowplayer](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/) API states the basic configuration is like this

```
$f("player1", "flowplayer.swf", {
    clip: {
        url: 'KimAronson-TwentySeconds59483.flv',
        autoPlay: true,
        autoBuffering: true
    },
    plugins: {
        controls: null
    },
    onLoad: function(){
        alert("player loaded");
    }
});
```

Note the  `controls: null` section this will allow you to render the player without controls.

Read [Flash plugins](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/#flash-plugins) section for more detailed information.